# Show measure zero: application of Theorem 1 in Lang (1986)?

Tags: probability, general-topology, measure-theory, convex-analysis, absolute-continuity

Suppose I have a random variable $Y$ with support $\{1,2,..., M\}$.

Consider a random vector $V\equiv (V_1, V_2,..., V_M)$ with support $\mathcal{V}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^M$ with positive Lebesgue measure. By definition of support we know that $\mathcal{V}$ is a closed set (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451478/support-of-random-variable-is-a-closed-set) for example).

All random variables/vectors are defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$.

For any $j\in \{1,...,M\}$, let $$\mathcal{V}_j\equiv \{v\equiv (v_1,..., v_M)\in \mathcal{V} \text{ s.t. } v_j\geq v_k \text{ }\forall k\in \{1,...,M\} \text{ with } k\neq j\}$$ Hence, $\{\mathcal{V}_1, ..., \mathcal{V}_M\}$ constitutes a partition of $\mathcal{V}$.

**Assumption A1:** $V$ has a distribution absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{V}$

**Assumption A2:** $Y\in argmax_{k\in \{1,...,M\}} V_k$ with probability 1.

---

**Question 1:** Is it true that $\mathcal{V}_j$ is closed and convex?

**Question 2:** Under which sufficient conditions I can claim $$\mathbb{P}(Y=j)=\mathbb{P}(V\in \mathcal{V}_j)$$ $\forall j\in \{1,..., M\}$.

---

**Attempted answer 1:** we know that if $\mathcal{V}=\mathbb{R}^M$, then $\mathcal{V}_j$ is closed and convex (see [here](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~nemirovs/OptIII_TR.pdf), for example). When $\mathcal{V}\subset \mathbb{R}^M$, I think **(can you confirm?)** we can generalise the same results for any **closed** $\mathcal{V}\subset \mathbb{R}^M$.

**Attempted answer 2:** by **A1**, I am tempted to naively set up the following proof:

wlog take $M=2$; for any $v\in \mathcal{V}$, suppose there exists $\{y,y'\}\subseteq argmax_{k\in \{1,2\}} v_k$ with $y\neq y'$. This can be the case if and only if 
$$
v_{y '}-v_y=0
$$
which is an event happening with probability measure zero, by A1, i.e.,
$$
\mathbb{P}(V \in \{v\in \mathcal{V} \text{ s.t. } v_1=v_2\} )=0
$$
Therefore, $argmax_{k} V_k$ is a singleton set almost surely.

This implies (not sure!)
$$\mathbb{P}(Y=j)=\mathbb{P}(V\in \mathcal{V}_j)$$ $\forall j\in \{1,2\}$.

---

**Doubts on the attempted answer 2:** my attempted proof does not use the fact that $\mathcal{V}$ is closed or the fact that $\mathcal{V}_j$ is closed-convex.

However, I am confused by Theorem 1 in [Lang (1986)](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01202504.pdf), which claims that **under A1 and if $\mathcal{A}$ is a convex subset of $\mathcal{V}$**, then $\mathbb{P}(V \in\partial \mathcal{A})=0$, where $\partial \mathcal{A}$ denotes the boundary of $\mathcal{A}$.

Any help to clarify? Is this Theorem relevant for my case? Referring to the case $M=2$, is $\partial \mathcal{V}_1\neq  \{v\in \mathcal{V} \text{ s.t. } v_1=v_2\}$?

Comment: The question has been clarified, sorry for the previous mess. Any hint would be extremely helpful

Comment: The definition of $\mathcal V_j$ does not make sense because there is no $j$ on the right side.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, sorry, a typo. Thank you

Comment: Any hint? Thank you

Comment: Do you mean $\mathcal V$ instead of $\mathbb R^M$ in the definition of the $\mathcal V_j$s?

Comment: (Assuming the answer to my comment above is "yes".) If $\mathcal V$ is convex, then all $\mathcal V_j$ are convex. But unless $\mathcal V$ is assumed (or proven) to be convex it is easy to construct examples where the $\mathcal V_j$s are not convex.

Comment: Question 2 implies that the probability spaces for $Y$ and $V$ are the same, but above you say that $V$ is defined on the product space.

Comment: Is Assumption 2 considered to be sample-wise, i.e., for each $\omega$ in $\Omega$? Or with probability 1, i.e., $\mathbb P[Y\in\operatorname{argmax}_{\{1,\dotsc,M\}}V]=1$?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have edited the errors and clarified the other points (I hope). Could you post an answer if you have some time?

Comment: @OskarLimka in particular, question 2 is making me to think a lot: do you think that Theorem 1 is any relevant for what I want to show?